# Mostrar Imagen desde el centro en un div

Tags: css, bootstrap

Buenas.
Tengo el siguiente problema, un archivo index que muestra fotos con la url desde una base de datos, cada foto esta ordenada en col-md-4 de bootstraps o sea que tengo 3 fotos por fila, 3 abajo , 3 abajo y asi.
El problema que tengo es que las fotos no tienen el mismo tamaño algunas son cuadradas y otras horizontales, esto hace que se me desarme el grid de bootstrap y no me queden las fotos ordenadas en 3 por fila, por mas que ponga img-responsive es lo mismo la forma de la imagen desarma el grid. Probe usando un codigo que corta segun un eje x e y la foto pero como todas las fotos no son iguales no se si lo que tengo que mostrar esta arriba a la derecha, al centro abajo, etc. Lo que necesito es poder mostrar la imagen desde el centro en el div y lo que salga por fuera del div que no lo muestre, como tiene facebook por ejemplo en las galerias, como ven las 3 imagenes de abajo son distintas, dos cuadradas y una rectangular pero la vista previa me las muestra a las 3 iguales solo que a la del rectangulo le muestra el centro. Encontre algo que se llamaba crop pero tampoco me sirvio, me dan una mano? Se lo que quiero hacer pero no se como buscarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Arme esto rapido recien:

```
<body>
   <br><br>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="col-md-4"><img src="imagenPrueba/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="overflow: hidden"></div>
               <div class="col-md-4"><img src="imagenPrueba/2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="overflow: hidden"></div>
               <div class="col-md-4"><img src="imagenPrueba/3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="overflow: hidden"></div>
               <div class="col-md-4"><img src="imagenPrueba/4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="overflow: hidden"></div>
               <div class="col-md-4"><img src="imagenPrueba/5.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="overflow: hidden"></div>
               <div class="col-md-4"><img src="imagenPrueba/6.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="overflow: hidden"></div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Si las imagenes no son iguales no me las muestra en cuadrado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intentaste colocarle al div contenedor de cada imagen el estilo overflow: hidden;?

Comment: Juan, publica el codigo reproduciendo el error si quieres una respuesta rapido.

Comment: Gracias Samuel, probe eso y nada pero ahi en otro foro me pasaron que use el estilo object-fit: cover; y me funciono

Comment: @Juan podrías publicar una respuesta con la solución que te funcionó y un ejemplo mostrando lo que obtuviste.

Comment: Ahi lo puse @Mariano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es lo que hice y como quedo:
Los datos los traigo de la base y meti el codigo de 4 columnas de bootstrap dentro de un while (Ese era el problema que tenia, full pantalla andaba ok, al achicar la pantalla si als imagenes no eran iguales la grilla de bootsrap se rompia)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="contenedor-img ejemplo-1 thumbnail">  
    <img src="<?php echo $row['carpeta'];?> " alt="" **style="width: 100%; height: 300px; object-fit: cover;"**>
       <div class="mascara">  
         <h2><b><?php echo $row['titulo'];?></b></h2>  
          <a href="<?php echo $row['direccion'];?>" class="link" style="margin-top: 15%;"><b>CLICK PARA VER GALERIA</b></a>  
        </div>  
        <div style="background-color: #000; color: #ffffff;">
            <center><label><h5><b><?php echo $row['titulo'];?></b></h5></label></center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pantalla completa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pantalla achicada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso era basicamente lo que necesitaba, que mantenga el tamaño del 100% del div y que la imagen se vea desde el centro, asi no se desarmaba el div de 4 columnas. Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es bastante simple, tuve el mismo problema y te recomiendo que lo mejor es poner un tamaño máximo y mínimo para todas las imágenes. Coloca esto en tu css y agregas esta clase a todos los col-md-4.

```
.content-img {
min-height: 160px;
max-height: 160px;
```

}

El tamaño de 160px es referencial, pon lo que mejor se acople a tus imágenes y claro cuando se haga click en alguna de tus imágenes cárgalo a un pop-up(Modal), no olvides puntuar esta respuesta sí te sirvió.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorge, lo acabo de solucionar poniendole este estilo a la imagen: style="width: 100%; height: 200px; object-fit: cover;"

Answer (score 0):

Yo tengo 2 sugerencias, una es usar **background-size: cover** y usar las imágenes como fondo en cada div, así:

```
.contenedor-img{ background-image: url('imagen.jpg'); background-size: cover; }
```

Lo otro que puedes hacer es usar la desconocida propiedad de **object-fit**, pero depende de un contenedor que es al que le debes aplicar las medidas deseadas, así:

```
.contenedor-img{ /*medidas deseadas*/}

.contenedor-img img { object-fit: cover; }
```

Lo único de esta propiedad es que hasta donde recuerdo no tiene buen soporte, pero si la retrocompatibilidad no es problema es una buena sugerencia.

Comment: object-fit es exactamente lo que use, muchas gracias Edgar.